# AutoCAD .DWF Circle Output Meaning

Tags: civil-engineering, drafting, autocad

My drafting program outputs a .dwf format file. In it, arcs are encoded as

```
(Circle 602331619,844923003 537072960 32715,65588)
```

where my so-far affirmed interpretation is `(Circle, X-center,Y-center Angle Unknown1,Unknown2)`.

The image for the arc is shown below (highlighted in Gold):

[image: The arc in concern is the highlighted on.]

Hence, each arc has its center and radius given. Are the pair of points at the end the starting and ending angles?

If you take `(32715,65588)` as `(3.2715 rad,6.5588 rad)`, the output starts making sense. Is this correct?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?  Some context might help us help you.  Also, is this a perfect half-circular arc?

Comment: This is a perfect half-circular arc. You may assume there is some negligible error in the theta span, but its theta span should be pi. I am trying to find the center point of the arc. In general, the arc can be in any orientation.

Comment: Ok.  That makes your assessment of the `32715,65588` a bit suspect, since if it were a perfect half-circle, I'd expect those to be `31416,62832`.  I tend to agree that that's probably what they represent, but I can't explain the difference.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. In fact, there is some error. The .dwf file states that there may be error, and I do not understand the format of the error statement. Thanks for the re-affirmation though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file format for *.dwf files is defined. A reference for the various drawing commands can be found [here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/whip/). Specifically, the definition of the `Draw Circle/Circular Arc/Circular Wedge function` is [here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/whip/DrwCircArcWdg.html).

From that link an arc is described by:

> X,Y,R Start,End

where:

> X,Y - Center point (in logical coordinates) of the circle to be drawn
>
> R - Radius (in logical coordinates) of the circle to be drawn
>
> Start, End - The angles (in 360/65,536ths of a degree) that describe a "pie-slice" of the full circle to be rendered; legal values range from 0 to 65,536

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was searching for my purpose! Unfortunately, I cannot increase your score yet until I get 15 reputation.